# Killing script with hardware control

Tags: bash, hardware

I have a script that controls an array of 12v relays depending on certain paramters. For an example: I am monitoring temperatures and pressures. If a temperature exceeds a certain value a relay will be pulled in to open vents and start fans. If the temperature drops to a certain value the relays are released and the vents will close and the fans will stop. Same with the pressures, which will open a solenoid valve and close it again depending on the pressure values.

All works fine and I am happy. The script (bash) is started at boot-up. However, sometimes the script dies mysteriously which leaves the relays in an "active" state.

Is there a way to ensure to reset the relays to "not-active" or "unenergized" when the script dies?

Comment: Yes, use the `trap` command to set the relays in *inactive* state on any `SIGTERM SIGINT` or `EXIT` signal. (see `man 7 signal` for additional information on standard signals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you can trap any of the signals your script can receive (except `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`) that are shutting it down and use `trap` to intercept the signal received and run the required commands to *reset the relays to "not-active" or "unenergized"* state before the process dies.

Using `trap` is quite easy. You simply *set a trap* at the top of your script listing the commands to be executed when a signal is caught. For simply commands you can do

```
trap 'command1; command2` SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT
```

to run `command1` and `command2` on receipt of any of the three listed signals. If you have a series of commands you need to execute, declare a function and then have `trap` execute the function on signal receipt, e.g.

```
cleanup () {
    # any number of commands to run
}

trap cleanup SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT
```

See `man 7 signals` for addition information on standard signals. Consult `man bash` (or search on "*using trap in bash*") for additional information on `trap`.